# I can't figure out how to word this WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have a (large) SQL query, but I'm getting stuck on how to word the **WHERE** section.

*I currently Have it wrote like this:*

```
AND (tbl_blocking.user != :who OR tbl_blocking.blocking != :who)
```

Which isn't really working correctly.
I'm trying to say, show the results **UNLESS** ':who' appears in the tbl_blocking.user **OR** tbl_blocking.blocking column

Currently, all that's happening, is all results are being brought out and repeated - **TWICE**.

**Example:**

[Status one!], [Status one!], [Status two!], [Status two!]

I'm sure it would help to see the entire query too, so here it is:

```
//Get status results
            $sql = "SELECT 

            tbl_status.id as statID, 
            tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
            tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
            tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
            tbl_status.date as statDATE,

            tbl_users.id as usrID, 
            tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
            tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
            tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

            tbl_blocking.id as blockID,
            tbl_blocking.user as blockUSER,
            tbl_blocking.blocking as blockBLOCKING,
            tbl_blocking.date as blockDATE,
            tbl_blocking.active as blockACTIVE,

            tbl_blocking2.id as blockID2,
            tbl_blocking2.user as blockUSER2,
            tbl_blocking2.blocking as blockBLOCKING2,
            tbl_blocking2.date as blockDATE2,
            tbl_blocking2.active as blockACTIVE2

            FROM tbl_status 

            LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
            LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking ON tbl_users.id = tbl_blocking.user
            LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking2 ON tbl_users.id = tbl_blocking2.user

            WHERE 
            tbl_status.deleted = '0'
            AND tbl_blocking.active = '0'
            AND (tbl_blocking.user != :who OR tbl_blocking.blocking != :who)

            ORDER BY 
            tbl_status.date desc

            LIMIT 200

            ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only items that don't have `:who` in *either* `tbl_blocking.user` *or* `tbl_blocking.blocking`, you simply want...

```
AND tbl_blocking.user != :who
AND tbl_blocking.blocking != :who
```

...there.

Because you're essentially saying, "Give me rows where `user` isn't `:who` *and* neither is `blocking`."

Comment: I don't think this would would because I'm not saying make sure :who is not present in both columns at the same time, I'm trying to check if it's in column 1 OR in column 2. If it appears in either of those columns - don't output the result

Comment: @ElaineAdams It would work. The above is checking to make sure `:who` isn't in *either* column. It would omit all rows where `:who` is in either column, regardless of whether it's in both or just one of them. That's what you want, based on your description.

Comment: No matter which answer I use to display my results, no results are shown since changing me code :(

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you *have* rows that have values of `deleted = 0`, `active = 0`, and don't have `:who` in either `blocking` or `user`?

Comment: I have discovered the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it. A user must have blocked another user in order to get their ID into the blocking table. Providing that they are not :who, their status is shown. The trouble being, if a user has never blocked anyone... they will never place information into the blocking table.. therefore, there status will never be shown

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your table structures are, but it sounds like generally speaking, you'll want to make sure your join is an outer one, to include users who aren't present in your blocking table.

Comment: I don't deny not understanding JOINs even after reading about them. They are a bit confusing. I've tried changing the JOIN to OUTER, but it doesnt work. I was thinking I could add an 'OR IS NULL' type of thing in somewhere?

Comment: @ElaineAdams: You already have outer joins. A `left join` is short for a `left outer join`. If you change it to `outer join` you get a `full outer join`, which is not the kind of outer join that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
AND tbl_blocking.user <> :who AND tbl_blocking.blocking <> :who
```

That is, you don't want `:who` in either column.

EDIT:

Your logic statement is:

- show the results UNLESS ':who' appears in the tbl_blocking.user OR tbl_blocking.blocking column

Here is a step by step transformation:

- show the results UNLESS (:who appears in the tbl_blocking.user or :who appears in the tbl_blocking.blocking column)
- show the results UNLESS (tbl_blocking.user = :who or tbl_blocking.blocking = :who)
- show the results WHERE NOT (tbl_blocking.user = :who or tbl_blocking.blocking = :who)
- show the results WHERE tbl_blocking.user <> :who AND tbl_blocking.blocking <> :who

EDIT II:

If the values can be `NULL`:

```
AND coalesce(tbl_blocking.user, '<null>') <> :who AND coalesce(tbl_blocking.blocking, '<null>') <> :who
```

Comment: So.. ugh, this is very confusing to me. Would that above statement mean, ensure that :who doesn't appear in EITHER column 1 or column 2, or does it mean, ensure it isnt in both columns at the same time?

Comment: @ElainAdams . . . It means `:who` is not in either column, that it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: When I replace my line of code, with any of the answers given here, No results are output anymore. Advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want both conditions to be true (i.e. both comparisons to be unequal), so you want to use the `and` operator:

```
AND (tbl_blocking.user != :who AND tbl_blocking.blocking != :who)
```

You can also write the same using `not` and `or`:

```
AND NOT (tbl_blocking.user = :who OR tbl_blocking.blocking = :who)
```

(In boolean logic `(not x) and (not y)` is equivalent to `not(x or y)`.)

Comment: OK, something seems to be happening. I'm using you're AND NOT example. Now, no results are being shown. But this must be because it will only show the results of a user, if they have blocked someone and have their ID in the blocking table. So I should add and OR NULL extention?

Comment: @ElaineAdams: Having the condition in the `where` clause turns the outer joins into inner joins. You should move the conditions for the blocking table from the `where` to the `on` clause of the joins. Add `AND tbl_blocking.active = '0' AND tbl_blocking.user = :who)` to one join and `AND tbl_blocking2.active = '0' AND  tbl_blocking2.blocking = :who` to the other. Now when you select data from `tbl_blocking` and `tbl_blocking2`, the values will be null where there is no matching record in the blocking table. You can also check for the null values in the `where` clause.

Comment: @ElaineAdams: Also, you should either change the join on the status table to `inner join`, or move the condition for that to its `on` clause, depending on which result you want when there is no corresponding record in the status table. If there always is one, use an `inner join`.